# Symfony2 cannot access to multiple files sent in POST form

Tags: forms, symfony, post, header

I'm having a real strange issue. I'm sending multiple files from one unique form in Symfony2. They seem to work properly, while I check `Network->headers` and they are there:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqycNCCLBhUXBkZAv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form[files]"; 
filename="image1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryqycNCCLBhUXBkZAv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form[files]"; 
filename="image2.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

But, when I try to get those files from the controller, it's going impossible to me to get them:

```
$form->handleRequest($request)->getData()
```

Only shows me one file (the 1st), `$request->files` works the same, only showing the 1st one.

It shouldn't be so complicated :/

This is my form code in the controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
    ->add('name')
    //->add('file')
    ->add('files', FileType::class, array(
        'attr' => array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'accept' => 'image/*',
            'multiple' => true
         )
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Do you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check the php configuration limit for file upload ? Just to be sure ^^' If not try with very little images

Comment: Did you try to declare an Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType of FileType

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the symfony multiple option true.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
             ->add('name')
            //->add('file')
             ->add('files', FileType::class, array(
                'multiple'=>true
                'attr' => array(
                    'data_class' => null,
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                )
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your answers. Finally I got the solution.

First of all, as Aleem said, we had to declare multiple upload files form when createFormBuilder:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'data_class' => null,
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                )
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

The problem with that is that Symfony tutorials are not ready for multiple files upload, so, it's tricky but there is a way to do it. Instead of

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
```

You have to:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
$data = $form->handleRequest($request)->getData();
```

Then inside $data you can find multiple UploadFile objects that can be foreached:

```
foreach ($data['file'] as $file) {
                $entity = new Entity();
                $entity->setFile($file);
                $entity->upload();

                $em->persist($entity);
                $em->flush();

            }
```

With that you can SetFile and upload by yourself, an operation typically done by $form->handleRequest.

In your Entity class, you cannot use Lifecycle Callbacks.

TY